# Why terminfo breaks my build on lack of versioned symbols in libtinfo.so?

Tags: haskell, terminfo

terminfo-0.4.1.4 breaks a build of hls not finding a specific version of some symbols from `libtinfo.so`, one of them being `tigetnum`.

There is also this warning, which I see when building other programs:

```
/lib64/libtinfo.so.5: no version information available (required by terminfo-0.4.1.4/libHSterminfo-0.4.1.4-ghc8.10.7.so)
```

The following is an error that breaks building of haskell-language-server:

```
terminfo-0.4.1.4/libHSterminfo-0.4.1.4-ghc8.10.7.so: error: undefined reference to 'tigetnum', version 'NCURSES_TINFO_5.0.19991023'
```

This is using versioned symbols feature of gcc stack, where you can have symbols with different versions in the same ELF file. However, my copy of libtinfo.so does not have versioned symbols and I don't see anything in terminfo code on github that would indicate it is requiring versioned symbols: that said I am not sure what I should be looking for, just grepped the srcs for the version.

objdump -x invoked on libHSterminfo-0.4.1.4-ghc8.10.7.so:

```
Version definitions:
1 0x01 0x057dc17f libHSterminfo-0.4.1.4-ghc8.10.7.so

Version References:
  required from libtinfo.so.5:
    0x02a6c513 0x00 02 NCURSES_TINFO_5.0.19991023
  required from libc.so.6:
    0x09691a75 0x00 03 GLIBC_2.2.5
```

Comment: Did you build `terminfo-0.4.1.4` yourself, or it came with ghc?

Comment: To help reproduce the problem, could you let us know (1) your Linux distribution and its version; (2) how you installed GHC; and (3) which version of GCC you're using (i.e., output of `gcc --version`), especially if it isn't the stock GCC for your distribution.

Comment: GHC is installed by stack, gcc is stock rhel7 I think: (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)

Comment: I happen to have libHSterminfo-0.4.1.4-ghc8.10.7.so installed by stack on my machine and it doesn't seem to reference versioned `tigetnum`. Can you run `nm --with-symbol-versions /path/to/your/libHSterminfo-0.4.1.4-ghc8.10.7.so | fgrep tigetnum`?

Comment: `nm` does not have this argument on my system. I added `objdump -x` output relevant to versions in the question description.

Comment: Mine doesn't have "required from libtinfo.so" section. My system like most today's Linuxes has libtinfo.so.6 though, and ghc sits under ghc-tinfo6-8.10.7. Perhaps just the build that does *not* use tinfo6 is broken. Maybe you can install ncurses6 and/or tinfo6 package on your machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, I believe this may be a Stack [issue](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/5561) where it downloads the wrong versions of GHC on CentOS/RHEL7 systems (i.e., downloading the Debian 9 version instead of the CentOS 7 version).

In order to work around this problem, you will first need to **manually clean out your `.stack` directory** to remove the offending binary packages.  The bad GHC version (tarfile and directory) will need to be removed from `.stack/programs/x86_64-linux`.  I also found I needed to clean out `.stack/snapshots` to avoid additional linkage errors, and I can't point you to exactly which files under there were the offenders.  It's honestly safest to wipe your entire `.stack` directory and start from scratch.

Anyway, I was able to build `haskell-language-server` in a CentOS 7 container as follows:

1. Ensure `ncurses-devel` and `zlib-devel` packages are installed.
2. Remove the entire `.stack` directory.
3. Run `stack update` to recreate a skeleton `.stack` directory.
4. Edit `.stack/config.yaml` to add the following clause:

   ```
    setup-info:
      ghc:
        linux64:
          8.10.7:
            url: "https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.10.7/ghc-8.10.7-x86_64-centos7-linux.tar.xz"
   ```

   Obviously, this is per-version configuration, so if you build with other GHC versions, you'll need to add additional subclauses.
5. Download and check out tag 1.7.0.0 of the HLS source:

   ```
   git clone -b 1.7.0.0 https://github.com/haskell/haskell-language-server
   ```
6. Build.

   ```
   $ cd haskell-language-server
   $ stack build
   [ . . . lots of output . . .]
   haskell-language-server           > Registering library for haskell-language-server-1.7.0.0..
   Completed 247 action(s).
   ```

Again, it's crucial that no stale binaries from `.stack` or the project-local `.stack-work` sneak into your build.  So removing `.stack` entirely and also building from a fresh Git clone of HLS will be safest.

Until this Stack bug is fixed,  you'll have to remain vigilant in adding additional clauses to `config.yaml` to avoid accidentally downloading a Debian build of some older or newer GHC version and wrecking your `.stack` cache.